# How to cache the connection string and access it?

Tags: c#, webforms, hashtable, connection-string

I want to cache the connection string and used cached object throughout my project. I tried like below

```
public static void Demo()
{
Hashtable Hashtable = new Hashtable()
Hashtable.Add("WEBConnectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WEBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
HttpContext.Current.Application["CachedValue"] = Hashtable;}

public static string Method(string key)
{
  string result = string.Empty;
  Hashtable CachedObject = (Hashtable)HttpContext.Current.Application["CachedValue"];
  if (CachedObject != null && CachedObject.ContainsKey(key))
   { 
      result = CachedObject[key].ToString();
   }
return result;
}
```

and accessing like this

```
string conString = Utility.Method("WEBConnectionString");
```

but `CachedObject.ContainsKey(key)` condition getting false. What am I doing wrong here? or is there any other method to cache the connection string.

Comment: What kind of web application is this? MVC? Web Forms?

Comment: Well, you could use an IOC container and DI and have the software automatically provide instances of your database context - but I'm more curious as to why you don't see the current  place where the connection strings love (config file/configuration manager) as a cache that's available through your entire project?

Comment: @mason Web Forms

Comment: Why don't you just access the `ConfigurationManager` instead and skip the caching?

Comment: @Train that is the requirement. I have to

Comment: @Mhd Who gave you that requirement? How did they determine that caching would be a worthwhile endeavor?

Comment: thats true though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (in a somewhat generic way):

```
public class HttpContextCache
{
    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(key);
    }

    public void Store(string key, object data)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, data);
    }

    public T Retrieve<T>(string key)
    {
        T itemStored = (T)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(key);
        if (itemStored == null)
        {
            itemStored = default(T);
        }

        return itemStored;
    }
}
```

Anywhere you find appropriate in your code:

```
// cache the connection string
HttpContextCache cache = new HttpContextCache();
cache.Store("WEBConnectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WEBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

// ...

// get connection string from the cache
HttpContextCache cache = new HttpContextCache();
string conString = cache.Retrieve<string>("WEBConnectionString");
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is why would you cache it? It's configuration data and should be quick enough to fetch every time you need it.

If you really need caching, there are more modern alternatives to HttpContext.Current.Application.

You can use a IOC container as suggested in the comments and configure it as a singletion instance. Seems overkill to setup a IOC container for that purpose though. If you're having multiple servers and you want to make sure they have the same state consider using a distributed cache like Redis.

Other alternatives are storing the connection string in a static variable, use [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.8), HttpRuntime.Cache or HttpContext.Current.Cache.

Example using a lazy static variable:

```
private static Lazy<string> ConnectionString = new Lazy<string>(() => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

// Access the connection string: var connectionString = ConnectionString.Value;
```